# Incorrect Use of wpdb::prepare()

Tags: wpdb

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I did not write this code however I am receiving the following error in WordPress:

The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder.
This message was added in version 3.9.

```
<?php

        echo '<div class="client_list"><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" value="0" class="" id="check_all" /> Check All</div>';


        $send_message_lists = get_post_meta($post->ID, wpvbxcon::smslist_smsclient, true);
        if(!is_array($send_message_lists))
            $send_message_lists = array();
        //print_r($send_message_lists);
        foreach($lists as $list)
            {   

                $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta m JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON p.ID = m.post_id WHERE meta_key = '_wpvbx_subscription' AND meta_value = $list->ID AND post_status = 'publish';";
                $subscriber_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($q));

                $checked = '';
                if(in_array($list->ID, $send_message_lists))
                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';

                if( current_user_can( '_wpvbx_access_list_'.$list->ID ) || current_user_can('administrator') )
                    printf('<div class="client_list"><input type="checkbox" name="lists[]" value="%d" class="list" %s /> %s (%d)</div>', $list->ID, $checked, $list->post_title, $subscriber_count);
            }
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"> </div>';


        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to replace the `meta_value = $list->ID` part with the placeholder `meta_value = %d`. Then use the following:

```
$subscriber_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $q, $list->ID ) );
```

where the input argument `$list->ID` will be treated as an *integer* (signed).

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders):

> The query parameter for prepare accepts `sprintf()`-like placeholders.
>   The `%s` (string), `%d` (integer) and `%f` (float) formats are supported.
>   (The `%s` and `%d` placeholders have been available since the function was
>   added to core in Version 2.3, `%f` has only been available since Version
>   3.3.) Any other % characters may cause parsing errors unless they are escaped. All `%` characters inside SQL string literals, including `LIKE`
>   wildcards, must be double-`%` escaped as `%%`. All of `%d`, `%f`, and `%s` are
>   to be left unquoted in the query string. Note that the `%d` placeholder
>   only accepts integers, so you can't pass numbers that have comma
>   values via `%d`. If you need comma values, use `%f` as float instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I have made the suggested changes however this appears to have slightly broken the page.  Now when going to the page to create a new message, all metaboxes do not fully load and dashboard menu items with submenus do not appear.

Comment: That most likely means you got an error in the PHP syntax. Always take a backup before changing anything. What does the current version look like?